# What is the difference between ∃x∀y and ∀y∃x?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

What is the exact difference between ∃x∀y(condition) and ∀y∃x(condition)? Translating these into English,

- ∃x∀y(condition) = There is an x for all y such that (condition) is satisfied.
- ∀y∃x(condition) = For all y, there is an x such that (condition) is satisfied.

These two seem to be different on the surface, but I could not grasp a vivid understanding of it. Also, I would want to ask how the difference in orders of quantifiers impact the final result.

Comment: Pointwise vs. uniform convergence, for example.

Comment: "For every natural number $n$ there is a greater one" vs "There is a natural number that is greater than every natural number"

Comment: The statement $\exists x \, \forall y \, (x+y=0)$ is false. It states that there is a *fixed number* $x$ that has the property that for all $y$, $x+y=0$. On the other hand, the statement, the statement $\forall y \, \exists x \, (x+y=0)$ is true, as in this case the value $x$ *is* allowed to depend on the value of $y$. So we can let $x=-y$. In general, the variables introduced by quanitifers are only allowed to depend on the variables that are introduced earlier in the statement.

Comment: The former: “There’s a chicken in every pot.”  The latter: “There’s one particular chicken that is in every pot simultaneously.”  Clearly one statement is much stronger, and implies the other.

Answer (score 1):

You have translated the sentence $\exists x \forall y$ (condition) incorrectly.

It means: there exists an $x$ such that for all $y$ (condition).
This means that there is just this on single $x$ that works for all $y$ simultaneously.

The sentence $\forall y \exists x$ (condition), means that I can choose a different $x$ for every $y$.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying, you are interpreting his grammar as similar to the statement "there is a time for every thing" .  I think he probably didn't mean it that way, but it is worth asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The first condition is stronger then the second one.

An illustration: every person has a mother (his own mother), but there's no a mother of every person.